# How to test net.tcp binding WCF web services in Jmeter and soapui?

Tags: web-services, wcf, performance-testing, load-testing

I am unable to test net.tcp wcf services in jmeter and soap ui.
it is showing Response message: java.net.UnknownHostException: net.tcp://******/WcfServiceLibrary1.Service1.svc/mex..your quick response will be help full.

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should use JMeter's [TCP Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#TCP_Sampler) for this instead of [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler which supports only http, https anf file protocols.

I also think you will find [How To Send Control Characters Using The JMeter TCP Sampler?](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733759-How-to-Send-Control-Characters-Using-the-JMeter-TCP-Sampler-) article useful when it comes to sending non-alphanumeric data